# Custom request validators for Multiple arrayed inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 1 form, with multiple inputs. each section can have multiple inputs, I want to create a `Form Validator` inside `Requests` for they, but don't know how to do it... This is currently how I am doing it:

```
public function postCreateResume(Request $request, Resume $resume, Education $education)
{

    /* 
     * begin a transaction, because we 
     * are doing multiple queries
     */
    DB::beginTransaction();

    /*
     * first we must create the resume, then  we 
     * can use the id for the following rows
     */
    $this->validate($education, [
        'resume_title' => 'required',
        'expected_level' => 'required',
        'salary' => 'required',
        'work_location' => 'required',
        'year_experience' => 'required',
        'about' => 'required',
    ]);     

    $resume->name = $request['resume_title'];
    $resume->work_level = $request['expected_level'];
    $resume->salary = $request['expected_salary'];
    $resume->country = $request['work_location'];
    $resume->total_experience = $request['year_experience'];
    $resume->about = $request['about'];
    $resume->save();

    // a user can have multiple educations on their cv
    foreach($request->input('education') as $education){

        $this->validate($education, [
            'institution' => 'required',
            'degree' => 'required',
            'year_begin' => 'required',
            'year_finish' => 'required',
            'about' => 'required',
        ]);

        // passed our checks, insert
        $education->resume_id = $resume->id;
        $education->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $education->institute = $education['institution'];
        $education->degree = $education['degree'];
        $education->summary = $education['about'];
        $education->started = $education['year_begin'];
        $education->ended = $education['year_finish'];

        if(!$education->save()){
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors("There was an error creating this resume")->withInput();
        }
    }

    // a user can have multiple employment on their cv
    foreach($request->input('experience') as $employment){

        $this->validate($employment, [
            'company' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'year_begin' => 'required',
            'year_finish' => 'required',
            'notes' => 'required',
        ]);

        // passed our checks, insert
        $employment->resume_id = $resume->id;
        $employment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $employment->name = $employment['title'];
        $employment->company = $employment['company'];
        $employment->country = $employment['country'];
        $employment->started = $employment['year_begin'];
        $employment->ended = $employment['year_finish'];
        $employment->summary = $employment['notes'];

        if(!$employment->save()){
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors("There was an error creating this resume")->withInput();
        }
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess("You have created a resume")->withInput();
}
```

Notice I have the validate inside each of the `foreach` in case the user has chosen more than 1 (in this example) `work experience`, or `education`, what I am trying to do is move the `$this->validate` inside the Requests folder, how can I achieve this?

I am using a `foreach` because I can have unlimited sections, see the image as to why;

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/74c7657e7b561f823a8b3960bc056511.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since laravel 5.4 you can pass arrays to the validator itself, for exaple

```
<input name="myarray[0]['test'] type="text">
```

Can now be validated like so

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'myarray.*.test' => 'required'
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays

Validating array based form input fields doesn't have to be a pain. For example, to validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

Likewise, you may use the * character when specifying your validation messages in your language files, making it a breeze to use a single validation message for array based fields:

```
'custom' => [
    'person.*.email' => [
        'unique' => 'Each person must have a unique e-mail address',
    ]
],
```